# Where/How to define a submit destination for my self created form (Vue) component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to re-use a form component through my website, but the submit button will have to handle different things every time (display different data, depending which page is calling the form-component)

I'm a little bit new to paying around with Vue components and passing data between them, up until now I did messy one-page apps.

My current plan is have the form get the inputs/filters (from the form component), and when clicking submit, it should send this data (somehow?) to the element that called it - and will know how to handle it to the specific case from where it was called. I hope this is the right approach to this kind of scenario (?).

- Is my plan a proper use of Vue / a proper way to submit a form from an external form-component?
- In what way do I trigger the submit to send data / run a method outside of my `DashboardForm.vue` component?
- How do I send fetched data of `DashboardForm.vue` component from `ReportType1.vue` and re-use this functionality in `ReportType2.vue`.

This is my Vue Form component (`DashboardForm.vue`):

```
<template>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">

                    <form id="mainForm" class="form-material row" method="POST">
                        <div class="" id="date-range">
                            <datepicker v-model="startDate" input-class="form-control inputDate" placeholder="Start Date" required></datepicker>
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <span class="input-group-text b-0 text-white"> to </span>
                            </div>
                            <datepicker v-model="endDate" input-class="form-control inputDate" placeholder="End Date" required></datepicker>
                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-info waves-effect waves-light" v-on:click="groupFilterDisplay(true);" value="Filter by Group"/>
                            <!-- <input type="button" id="submit-btn" class="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light" v-on:click="loadNew" value="Submit"/> -->
                            <input type="button" id="submit-btn" class="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light" value="Submit"/>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <transition name="fade">
            <div id="groupFilter" class="popupGroupFilter" v-if="groupFilter">
                <div id="filterArea">
                    <input type="text" v-model="searchGroupInput" placeholder="Search" class="gfSearch">
                    <span class="gfTitle">Filter by Group</span>
                    <hr>
                </div>
                <div class="ulTree">
                    <ul>
                        <tree_item class="item" v-bind:model="groupTree"></tree_item>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div v-on:click="applyGroupFilter();" class="gfClose gfApply"><span>✔ Apply</span></div>
                <div v-on:click="groupFilterDisplay(false);" class="gfClose"><span>X Close</span></div>
            </div>
        </transition>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
// import { GF } from '../mixins/GF.js';

export default {
    name: 'DashboardForm',
    // mixins: [GF],
    data() {
        return {
            groupTree:          window.groups,
            searchGroupInput:   '',
            searchGroupArray:   [],
            groupFilterApplied: false,
            groupFilterBackup:  [],
            selectedIds:        [],

            groupFilter:        false, 
            startDate:          null,
            endDate:            null,
            mode:               0,
        }
    },
    props: {
        options: Array
    },
    watch: {
        'searchGroupInput': function (newVal, oldVal) {
            this.groupTree = this.searchGroupResult();
        }
    },
    methods: {
        recurseGroups: function (arr, action) {
        },
        applyGroupFilter: function () {

        },
        groupFilterDisplay: function (display) {

        },
        searchGroupResult: function () {
        },
        fetchGroupIds: function () {
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

This is the component that uses the DashboardForm for example (
`ReportType1.vue`):

```
<script>
    import DashboardForm    from "../tools/DashboardForm.vue";

    export default {
        components: {
            DashboardForm
        },
        data() {
            return {
            };
        },
        created() {
        },
        mounted() {
        },
        destroyed() {
        },
        watch: {
        },
        methods: {
        }
    }
</script>

<!-- Template -->
<template>
    <div>

        <!-- Form -->
        <DashboardForm/>

        <!-- form result -->
        <div id="resultContainer"> <datatable/> </div>

    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay if I understood you well, we are trying to build a reusable form component.
I will give you a quick overview of how VUE components communicate.

1. The component takes its necessary inputs using the `props`.
2. The component inner HTML can be passed from its user by using `slot`.
3. The component fire events to tell its user that there is something happened inside me.

Example of the three cases:

Your component `my-form` template:

```
<form>
    <div class="row">
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" @click="onSubmit"></button>
            <button v-if="hasReset" class="btn btn-danger" @click="onReset"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Your component `js` file:

```
export default {
name: 'my-form',
data() {
    return {
    }
},
props: {
    reset: boolean
},
computed: {
    hasReset: function(){
        return this.reset;
    }
}
methods: {
    onSubmit: function(){
        let data = { "name": "dummy data" };
        this.$emit("submit", data);
    },
    onReset: function(){
        let data = { "name": "" };
        this.$emit("reset", data);
    }
}
}
```

After that, you can use `my-form` component as below:

```
<my-form :reset="formHasReset" @submit="onFormSubmit" @reset="onFormReset">
    <input class="col-12" type="text" name="name">
    <input class="col-12" type="text" name="username">
    <input class="col-12" type="password" name="password">
    <input class="col-12" type="email" name="email">
</my-form>
```

And the javascript is:

```
data(){
    formHasReset: true
},
methods: {
    onFormSubmit: function(data){
        console.log(data.name); //Should give you 'dummy data'
    },
    onFormReset: function(data){
        console.log(data.name); //Should give you ''             
    }
}
```

I hope it is clear now for you :).

Comment: I don't get the onSubmit part (`onSubmit` & `onFormSubmit` parts specifically) and what `this.$emit("submit", data);` does? - How does the data move to the main component from the form-component using these 2 methods

Comment: The `emit` fires an event ( to be specific a custom event ) like the native ones `click, keypress` ..... and the main component can listen to this event. so when we submit the `form` component fire `submit` event and the main component listens to it in the `ofFormSubmit` method.

Comment: oh great, thanks for making this to look simpler for me, I'll be netx to my pc tomorrow and will test this.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: Hi Nour. Isn't there a way to "sync" variables (like `v-model`) does, with variables from the child-components with the parent component? (without using any "setter" functions in the parent method section..